# Gnome-Screenshot on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-screenshot

I recently migrated from 16.04 to 18.04 clean install.

Before there was a shortcut to "Take a screenshot of an area" and then gave you the options to save it on the clipboard and/or save it on a directory. Now on 18.04, the option is not there.

Tried to test the command but can't find the combination of options to have the result I want, if it's still even there.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WMbZ7qH only have those options